# What is the major product of the reaction of 2-ethoxypentane with hydrogen iodide?

Tags: organic-chemistry

What is the major product formed by heating 2-ethoxypentane with $\ce{HI}$?

[image: 2-ethoxypentane]

The options are:

[image: Option 1: (2S)-2-methylbutan-1-ol]

[image: Option 2: 1-iodobutane]

According to me the correct answer should be option-1 because 2-methylbutyl carbocation is more stable than ethyl carbocation as there are more +I groups attached in 2-methylbutyl carbocation.
But according to my book the second option is correct.
Is my answer correct?
If not please explain

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, none of those answers are correct, provided your stem is right.
The reaction will start with protonation of the ether to give you the following species:

[image]

And the iodide nucleophile can attack either side via $S_{N}2$ mechanism. Since the left side is more accessible, it'll probably attack there first giving you:

[image]

Then, since we're still in the presence of HI and it is a strong acid, it protonates the alcohol and converts it into a corresponding alkyl iodide via either $S_N2$ like in the example above or $S_N1$:

[image]

A general rule of thumb here for the future reference is that in a hydrolysis of an ether with a strong hydrohalogen acid (HI, HBr), you get a mix of two corresponding alkyl halides with halogen where the oxygen used to be.

Comment: can you please explain how the left side is more accessible ? Is it because of less steric hindrance?

Comment: precisely so. Remember, that things constantly move, groups rotate around single bonds, so on the left you have a relatively small ethyl, while on the right you have a huge propeller of a group that will knock off anything that comes (or attempts to do so) close to attack that secondary carbon with the oxygen.